# Search O365 Group Site

Tags: sharepoint-online, search, office-365, enterprise-search, office-365-groups

I am wondering if anybody is aware how o365 groups and SharePoint search are related.

I have created an o365 Group site and added a custom content type, site column and content.

I have associated the new content with my custom content type and have added content to the custom site column.

If I go to the search in the top left hand corner I can return result by search on the custom column as expected.

When I go to the search center for the entire tenant https://tenant.sharepoint.com/search and try and find the same content from this group site it does not return content.

Also, if I go to the SharePoint admin center and the search settings I cannot see this column show up in the crawled properties.

Is the expected behavior for groups sites? Or am I missing something about search and crawling content within group sites?

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per my test in my SharePoint online, the content from group site can be searched in the search center for the entire tenant https://tenant.sharepoint.com/search.

In SharePoint online, full crawl is performed automatically. So, we will wait for full crawl.

You could wait for a period of time, then check if the content from group site can be searched in the search center.

Comment: You are right. This seems to be a inconsistent issue across our tenants. The tenant we use for "development and testing" we have this issue. on our "Production" tenant everything works as expected. I have raised a support ticket with premier support. Thanks.